# unity's streaming assets loading from another folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to put audio files in another folder and then recompile it when loading scene? I dont want to use streaming assets folder, I want to load it from other folder (i want to have it compiled).

Comment: [This link](http://www.hamzahasan.com/simple-sound-mechanism-unity/) might help you regarding sound mechanism

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this, you want to use the [Resources folder](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html). Create a folder called Resources, and you can load using the function:

```
public static Object Load(string path);
```

So something like this would work:

```
Resources.Load("music.mp3") as AudioClip;
```

Note that this can be computationally expensive, you might want to use `LoadAll` or `LoadAsync` to make things a bit less difficult on the system. See [Unity Resource documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it compiled as in part of the whole build, put the asset in any folder under Assets and create a reference into which you drag the asset.

```
public AudioClip audioClip;
```

StreamingAssets and Resources folder ships all items stored in them, this is because Unity is not able to define whether the asset will be used or not so it just ships it.

When you keep items under other folders, Unity will only ship (and build) them if it finds a reference. It checks for the meta files whether the asset is linked or not.

The difference in the build is that "shipped" assets are merged in the final build while Resources and StreamingAssets assets are stored in specific folders in data folder.